# Sequencing promises in AngularJS

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I'm trying to do the following:

- Function that returns a promise that **checks if a directory exists** (it creates is if it doesn't)
- Then copy a file to that created directory.

The way I'm doing it, the **copy the file part gets executed before the promise** itself! So it fails because there is no directory there yet!

Code: 
*IMG_DIR_ENTRY* is a global variable inside the controller.

**addImage**

```
function addImage(imageURI) {
        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {

            handleImgDirCreation().then(function(imageDirEntry) {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function onResolveImgSuccess(imgFileEntry) {
                    imgFileEntry.copyTo(imageDirEntry, "img_" + + new Date(), function onCopySuccess(copiedImgFileEntry) {
                        images.push(copiedImgFileEntry.toURL());
                        window.localStorage.setItem(IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(images));
                        resolve();
                    },
                    function onCopyFail(errMsgCopy) {
                        console.debug("ERROR: copy failed because: " + errMsgCopy);
                        reject();
                    });
                },
                function onResolveImgFail(errMsgResolveImg) {
                    console.debug("ERROR: couldn't resolve img because: " + errMsgResolveImg);
                    reject();
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

**handleImgDirCreation** (this is not getting called before the *.then()*)

```
function handleImgDirCreation() {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {

            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(IMAGE_DIR, function onDirExists(imageDirEntry) {
                console.debug("SUCCESS: Directorio images ya existe.");
                resolve(imageDirEntry);
            },
            function onNonExistent(errMsgNonExistent) {
                createImageDirectory("WARNING: Directory didn't exist... || " + errMsgNonExistent);
                resolve(IMG_DIR_ENTRY);
            });
        });
    }
```

**createImageDirectory**

```
function createImageDirectory(errMsg) {
        console.debug(errMsg);
        console.debug("Creating IMG DIR --> " + IMAGE_DIR);

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(DATA_DIRECTORY, function onResolveRootSuccess(rootDirEntry) {
            rootDirEntry.getDirectory('images', {create : true}, function onCreateDirSuccess(imgDirEntry) {
                console.debug("SUCCESS: Directory created --> " + imgDirEntry.toURL());
                IMG_DIR_ENTRY = imgDirEntry;
            },
            function onCreateDirFail(errMsgCreateDir) {
                console.debug("ERROR: Couldn't create image directory because: " + errMsgCreateDir);
            });
        },
        function onResolveRootFail(errMsgResolveRoot) {
            console.log("ERROR: Couldn't resolve root directory because: " + errMsgResolveRoot);
        });

    }
```

**IMPORTANT**
I'm doing it with async promises because otherwise Android's main thread (UI Thread) gets overloaded and blocked and skips frames. Maybe there is another approach that I do not know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have code wait for the directory to be created, the `createImageDirectory` function needs to return a promise:

```
function createImageDirectory(errMsg) {
    var future = $q.defer();
    console.debug(errMsg);
    console.debug("Creating IMG DIR --> " + IMAGE_DIR);

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(DATA_DIRECTORY, function onResolveRootSuccess(rootDirEntry) {
        rootDirEntry.getDirectory('images', {create : true}, function onCreateDirSuccess(imgDirEntry) {
            console.debug("SUCCESS: Directory created --> " + imgDirEntry.toURL());
            IMG_DIR_ENTRY = imgDirEntry;
            //RESOLVE with imgDirEntry;
            future.resolve(imgDirEntry);
        },
        function onCreateDirFail(errMsgCreateDir) {
            console.debug("ERROR: Couldn't create image directory because: " + errMsgCreateDir);
            //REJECT with error
            future.reject(errMsgCreateDir);
        });
    },
    function onResolveRootFail(errMsgResolveRoot) {
        console.log("ERROR: Couldn't resolve root directory because: " + errMsgResolveRoot);
        //REJECT with error
        future.reject(errMsgResolveRoot);
    });
    //RETURN promise
    return future.promise;

}
```

Then the `handleImgDirCreation` function needs to resolve with that promise:

```
function handleImgDirCreation() {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(IMAGE_DIR, function onDirExists(imageDirEntry) {
            console.debug("SUCCESS: Directorio images ya existe.");
            resolve(imageDirEntry);
        },
        function onNonExistent(errMsgNonExistent) {
            //createImageDirectory("WARNING: Directory didn't exist... || " + errMsgNonExistent);
            //resolve(IMG_DIR_ENTRY);
            var msg = "WARNING: Directory didn't exist... || " + errMsgNonExistent
            var directoryPromise = createImageDirectory(msg)
            //RESOLVE with directory promise
            resolve(directoryPromise);
        });
    });
}
```

By resolving with a directory creation promise, subsequent methods chained from that promise will wait for the creation of the directory.

> Since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.
>
> [— AngularJS $q Service API Reference (Chaining Promises)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)